# When Reading "" in VSTO using Document.Range,text is read as "".This is UTF-32 and C# uses UTF-16 for strings.How to read text as ""

Tags: c#, vsto, utf-16, utf-32

```
string data = doc.Range(start, end).Text(); //text inserted is "" <br>
MessageBox.Show(data); <br>
return;
```

Comment: translate the charset? I'd be highly surprised if c# couldn't do utf8<->16<->32 conversions.

Comment: @MarcB , so how do I convert 32 into 16 bit encoding ?

Comment: Do you mean literally what's in the subject (most of which should be in the Question text, not in the subject)? The document contains only the letter *x* and when you print out to a MessageBox you see *xx*? Or are you using "x" as a placeholder? In my experience, C# reads *exactly* what's in Word - there's no "oddness" with UTF character sets for anything falling in the ANSI code-set, which "x" certainly does. I can also tell you that the way you determine doc.Range will also contain an ANSI 13 (\n or \r in C#). So if you mean you get two *characters* instead of just one, that's expected.